# why fopen() or open() use errno instead of just returning error code?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, errno

In usual case  `open()` return the new file descriptor, or -1 if an error occurred  and in that case, `errno` is set appropriately.

I am not understanding why this mechanism of `errno` is used here? whats the purpose of here? why just we can not map all error with some negative return no?

like

```
fd = open("/dev/tty0", O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
if(fd == -1)
  printf("this is EACCES error");
else if (fd == -2)
    printf("this is EPERM error");
```

Is there any benifit of `errno`  mechanism.? if yes then i would like to know/understand then in other things i can also use this mechanism.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since `fopen` returns a `FILE*` you can't expect it to return an error code in that pointer: the only "special" value for pointers is `0`.

As you observe, for `open` this restriction doesn't hold. In fact systems as linux do exactly what you propose in their lower levels. The system call under the hood returns the negative error code if things go wrong. That (negated) code is then plug into `errno` by a shallow user space wrapper which then returns the `-1` to indicate the error to the application.

The reason that this is done so is purely historical. In good old times there was no threading and `errno` was still just a simple global variable. At that time the chosen strategy incurred not much overhead and probably seemed an acceptable way to communicate between OS and application. Since such interfaces basically can't be changed without breaking a lot of code, we will be stuck with `errno` as a pseudo variable that is thread local.

This is not ideal, but the overhead is not as bad as it sounds, since these are clearly *error* indications that should occur only exceptionally.

Answer (score 9):

For me the advantage is that getting the error information is unified in that way, returning some negative value would work OK with `open` as it returns an integer, but `fopen` returns a `FILE *` so another technique would have to be used there.

Comment: FILE* is still pointer to some buffer/memory so that will never be negative so if error occured then dont we return FILE* with negative value? because NULL is 0

Comment: A pointer has - at least on the architectures I know - no concept of signedness, it can (theoretically) cover the entire range of the "underlying unsigned integer" (ie a 32bit point can go from 0x00000000 to 0xffffffff).  And `NULL` is just and indication to say "hey, this failed, look at errno to see what went wrong"

Comment: In theory a set of reserved pointers could be used too; all that's needed is `char err_ptrs[MAX_ERRNO]; void *EACCESS_ptr = err_ptrs+EACCESS;` etc. to make `EACCESS_ptr` a valid "error code" for pointers. However, having to duplicate them as integers and pointers, and the fact that some interfaces use the entire space of integer values as valid returns, still makes errno worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

`errno` is an error code. It is important to map the errors to what is actually happening so you can make strategic decisions in your code on what to do next. For instance, `ERANGE` which is defined in `errno.h`, will tell you that the result of `strtol("0xfffffffff",NULL,0)` is out of that function's range. More importantly in your example, it is good to know whether you have an `EACCES` or `EPERM` error so you know how to handle the file.

You can't map all problems with one error code since you could have multiple issues that you would like to catch and handle. When I say catch, I do not mean try/catch.

The use of errno establishes and error handling mechanism so you get more information than just -1.

ERANGE, EACCES, EPERM, and others are considered macros that map to a particular error number for convenience purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Giving each function a distinct set of return values makes it overly complicated to write code in a generic fashion. With the current semantics, you can adopt a universal pattern:

```
int fd;
if ((fd = some_function(arg1, arg2)) == -1)
{
    perror("some_function");
    exit(1);
}
```

You can even wrap this in a macro:

```
#define CALL_OR_DIE(function, ret, ...)      \
    if ((ret = function(__VA_ARGS__)) == -1) \
    { perror(#function); exit(1); }
```

Usage:

```c
int fd;
CALL_OR_DIE(open, fd, "/dev/tty0", O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
```

Comment: So you're basically saying (1) it's better to write `== -1` than `< 0` (with errnos defined to be negative), and (2) this is the motivation for `errno`? I suppose there is a benefit in not having to pass `fd` to `perror` in the failure case, because it can be read from the thread-local `errno`, but I don't think it wholly explains why the errno isn't returned from `open` as well.